# Post and decode JSON In Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to post an associative array to another Node.js server, internaly to my server:

First server does a `POST` request like this with [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request):

```
var request = require('request');
request.post('http://localhost:8084/',{ json: {"isposted": {"ok":"val"}}});
```

Second server's result is this:

```
{ '{"isposted":{"ok":"val"}}': '' }
```

Instead of:

```
{"isposted":{"ok":"val"}}
```

Server's (2nd) source code to parse the data is this:

```js
var http = require('http');
var qs = require('qs');

var processRequest = function(req,callback) {
    var body='';
    req.on('data', function(data) { body+=data; });
    req.on('end',  function() { callback(qs.parse(body)); });
}

var server2 = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    processRequest(req,function(data){
        try
        {
            data=JSON.parse(data.jsonData);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            data=data;
        }
        console.log(data);
    });
 });
```

Comment: Someone edited my post, and removed the important information...

Comment: And now people down-voting it because the edit was making no sense

Comment: Sorry, I've missed a part in the first edit - the last edit you rolled back had all the information of your original post, but well formatted

Comment: Your request code has an extra `}` in it, and I've no idea where `request` is coming from. Presumably you are requiring some module, but which one and where is the code for it? It's hard to help you if you don't create [a proper test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (I haven't even looked at the server half of this yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) is the wrong package to decode JSON like this: `callback(qs.parse(body));`. Try just using JSON.parse like this: `callback(JSON.parse(body));`

Try this to support different types of encoding:

```
req.on('end',  function(){ 
    if ('application/json' === req.headers['content-type']) {
        callback(JSON.parse(body)); 
    }
    else {
        callback(qs.parse(body));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it's working! But I also need qs.parse to decode data posted as GET, How can I decide if it should be parsed with JSON or QS?

Comment: You can use for instance [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) and decide based on `Content-Type`-header, which is the recommended way to do it.

Comment: thanks, but I am not using express and I can't figure how to determine what is the Content-Type. I figured it's stated in res["_header"], but seems difficult to just extract the content-type from it

Comment: Nevermind, I found using req.headers['content-type']